# Eclipse+gtest compile c++ error:multiple definition of "...."

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, googletest

I have project like this: 
[image]

When I try to compile this,get error:multipe definition of `FooTest_failing_Test:TestBody()'

I have compiled gtest 1.7 and gmock 1.7,and copied all libg* to /user/lib,and my build setting like this:
[image]

[image]

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Please consider posting your questions in text format. Images are not searchable, not compilable, take up bandwidth, not readable on small devices, and like any external resource tend to disappear in the intertubes. Just because you can capture, upload and paste URL in two clicks doesn't mean you should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FootTest.cpp is being compiled twice because it is being #include(d) in AllTests.cpp.  This produces the symbol twice that you are seeing.  I don't think you need to include FooTest.cpp in AllTests.cpp.

Comment: You are right,and I need to replace #include "FooTest.cpp" with
#include "gtest/gtest.h",thank you very much.